# Stream stop get new data when finishing fetch all data and new payment was created

Tags: transactions, java-sdk, horizon, stream

I using java-stellar-sdk version 0.2.0 from this: https://github.com/stellar/java-stellar-sdk/releases
I did as tutorial example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getTransaction();
}


private void getTransaction(){
    Server server = new Server("https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org");
    KeyPair  account = KeyPair.fromAccountId(myPublicKey");

    PaymentsRequestBuilder paymentsRequest = server.payments().forAccount(account);

    String lastToken = null;
    if (lastToken != null) {
        paymentsRequest.cursor(lastToken);
    }

    paymentsRequest.stream(new org.stellar.sdk.requests.EventListener<OperationResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(OperationResponse payment) {
            Log.d("tag","last token:"+payment.getPagingToken());
            //savePagingToken(payment.getPagingToken());

            if (payment instanceof PaymentOperationResponse) {
                String amount = ((PaymentOperationResponse) payment).getAmount();
                Asset asset = ((PaymentOperationResponse) payment).getAsset();
                String assetName;
                if (asset.equals(new AssetTypeNative())) {
                    assetName = "lumens";
                } else {
                    StringBuilder assetNameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    assetNameBuilder.append(((AssetTypeCreditAlphaNum) asset).getCode());
                    assetNameBuilder.append(":");
                    assetNameBuilder.append(((AssetTypeCreditAlphaNum) asset).getIssuer().getAccountId());
                    assetName = assetNameBuilder.toString();
                }

                StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
                output.append(amount);
                output.append(" ");
                output.append(assetName);
                output.append(" from ");
                output.append(((PaymentOperationResponse) payment).getFrom().getAccountId());
                Log.d("tag",output.toString());
            }

        }
    });

}
```

**When it start streaming data, I got this exception, but the streaming continue getting data to the end**

```
> 06-08 13:27:31.130 13894-14001/com.mypackage.testcreatestellaraccount
> W/Errors: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2
> service reification failed for
> [org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.DataSourceProvider] with an
> exception:
>     MultiException stack 1 of 4
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataSource
>         at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:315)
>         at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl.getAllMethods(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:108)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.findInitializerMethods(Utilities.java:1344)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DefaultClassAnalyzer.getInitializerMethods(DefaultClassAnalyzer.java:107)
>         at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getInitializerMethods(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:242)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getInitMethods(Utilities.java:219)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:144)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:179)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.internalReify(SystemDescriptor.java:723)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:678)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:463)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2187)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$1200(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:121)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$10.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1331)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$10.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1326)
>         at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:115)
>         at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:111)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>         at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(LRUHybridCache.java:173)
>         at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:292)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1388)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1313)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1302)
>         at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getServiceHandles(Providers.java:354)
>         at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getCustomProviders(Providers.java:201)
>         at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.<init>(MessageBodyFactory.java:221)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
>         at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1350)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:271)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:365)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
>         at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>         at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
>         at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:767)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getUnqualifiedService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:774)
>         at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.IterableProviderImpl.get(IterableProviderImpl.java:111)
>       at org.glassfish.jerse 06-08 13:27:31.150 1343-1349/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build
> property
```

**My question is:
After finish getting all payments, wait for a few minutes, I made another new payment, but streaming seem does not work anymore, it does not go to onEvent() to process to get my new payment (both send/receive payment)

Anyone has any solutions or suggestions, please Help!**

Answer (score 1):

after long time digging, I found the problem:

it's because library org.glassfish.jersey's bug at: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/3537

the http close after 60s the throw exception:

javax.ws.rs.ServerErrorException: HTTP 504 Gateway Time-out

My solution is working around:

check when eventSource.isOpen=false, I will call stream again with timer

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EventSource eventSource = getTransaction();

    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!eventSource.isOpen()){
                eventSource= getTransaction();
            }
        }
    }, 10000,10000);
}

private EventSource getTransaction(){
    //.... same code above

    EventSource eventSource = paymentsRequest.stream(new org.stellar.sdk.requests.EventListener<OperationResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(OperationResponse payment) {
            //.... same code above
            }

        }
    });
    return eventSource;

}
```

Hope in the future, stellar and org.glassfish.jersey will fix this problem